# Is there an API or method for querying the first and last data in this project?

Tags: flutter, go, software-distribution, objectbox

Is there an API or method for querying the first and last data in objectbox-go.

Similar to the First() and Last() methods in Gorm.

I need to use this method to query one by one and then send the data to the server.But I haven't found any relevant methods in objectbox-go.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "Flutter"? objectbox-go has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

1. Get all relevant objects at once and iterate over them to send them one-by-one. Typically you use a [Query](https://golang.objectbox.io/queries) to get data.
2. Get all IDs, iterate over them: in each iteration, get the actual object for the ID and send it to the server; E.g. use [query.FindIds()](https://golang.objectbox.io/queries#working-with-query-results)
3. Use queries with [offset and limit for pagination](https://golang.objectbox.io/queries#limit-offset).

The ID based approach is likely the most resource friendly if you have lots of objects. If you have only a couple of hundred objects or less, you can go with the first approach, which is the simplest one.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Object-box query that works for me.

```
final query = _studyBox.query().order(Study_.date).build();
Study? aStudy = query.find().lastOrNull;
```